# Derivative of $V(w)$ w.r.t $w$ with $w = f(x,y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find the following derivative: $V^{'}(w)$ with $w = f(x,y)$.

I guess that I can express it as:

$$V^{'}(w) = \frac{\partial V(f(x,y))}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial V(f(x,y))}{\partial y}, $$

but I am unable to find a formal justification. Can you help me?

Comment: What do you mean by derivative? You can find the gradient of such a function, you can find its total differential, etc., but what does derivative mean to you here? What do you need it for?

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, always reduce everything the limit definition of the derivative and crunch. As has often been said, [shut up and calculuate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shut_up_and_calculate).

Let's first calculate the partial derivative. I assume that $V: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, and $f: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$. I will denote
$V$ as $V(w)$ and $f$ as $f(x, y)$. 
We want to find the derivatives of $P \equiv (V \circ f): \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$. That is, $P(x, y) \equiv V(f(x, y))$. We will calculate the derivatives starting from first principles:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}(x_0, y_0)
&= \lim_{dx_0 \rightarrow 0}
\frac{P(x_0 + dx_0, y_0) - P(x_0, y_0)}{dx_0} \\
%
&=  \lim_{dx_0 \rightarrow 0}
\frac{ V(f(x_0 + dx_0, y_0)) - V(f(x_0, y_0))}{dx_0} \\
%
&=  \lim_{dx_0 \rightarrow 0}
\frac{ V\left(f(x_0, y_0) + dx_0\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0, y_0)\right) - V(f(x_0, y_0))}{dx_0} \\
%
&= \lim_{dx_0 \rightarrow 0} \frac{ V(f(x_0, y_0)) + dx_0\frac{\partial V}{\partial w}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0, y_0)\right) - V(f(x_0, y_0))}{dx_0} \\ 
&= \frac{dx_0\frac{\partial V}{\partial w}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0, y_0)\right)}{dx_0} \\
%
&=\frac{\partial V}{\partial w}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0, y_0)\right)
\end{align*}